# Dom split text in headers and paragraphs

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, dom

I have a Html string like this:

```
<h2>Header 1</h2>
  <p>Example line 1</p>
  <p>Example line 2</p>
  <p>Example line 3</p>
<h2>Header 2</h2>
  <p>Example line 1</p>
  <p>Example line 2</p>
...
```

I eventually want to convert this to Twitter Bootstrap tabs Html. To be able to do that I prefer to have the string in one (or two) array(s):

```
'Header 1' => '<p>Example line 1</p><p>Example line 2</p><p>Example line 3</p>'
'Header 2' => '<p>Example line 1</p><p>Example line 2</p>'
```

**What I have now:**

```
$source = new \Htmldom();
$source->load($string);

foreach ($source->find('h2') as $item)
  {
    $tabs[] = $item->innertext;
    $panels[] = $item->next_sibling()->innertext;
  }
```

This gives me an array with the headers and an array with the first sibling of these headers (paragraphs in this example):

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'Header 1' (length=10)
  1 => string 'Header 2' (length=9)

array (size=2)
  0 => string '<p>Example line 1</p>' (length=312)
  1 => string '<p>Example line 1</p>' (length=112)
```

Of course I want to have all the paragraphs, not just the first ones. It seems to me that this is not possible with this approach. Am I wrong? How can I achieve this?

Comment: I can see that `</h2` are not closed. Is it a typo only in this post, or also in your code?

Comment: Please also give us link to library which you're using to parse HTML.

Comment: @michail_w Typo, fixed it! The library is SimplePHPDom. Or any other for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

try to loop over elements and stop loop on h2.

EXAMPLE:

```
foreach ($source->find('h2') as $item)
  {
    $tabs[] = $item->innertext;
    $next_sibling=true;
    $item_next=$item;    
    while($next_sibling){
        $item_next=$item_next->next_sibling();
        $panels[$item->innertext][] = $item_next->innertext;
        if($item_next->next_sibling() == null || $item_next->next_sibling()->tag == 'h2')
            $next_sibling=false;    

    }        
  }  var_dump($tabs); var_dump($panels);
```

o/p:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'Header 1' (length=8)
  1 => string 'Header 2' (length=8)
array (size=2)
  'Header 1' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Example line 1' (length=14)
      1 => string 'Example line 2' (length=14)
      2 => string 'Example line 3' (length=14)
  'Header 2' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Example line 1' (length=14)
      1 => string 'Example line 2' (length=14)
```